# Валидация данных в форме с загрузкой их в БД PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть две функции и я не могу их правильно скрестить. Как поступить чтобы при условии что данные прошли успешно проверку, они были загружены в БД? Сама по себе функция addComment работает корректно

```
function addComment(string $name, string $content): void
{
    global $pdo;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (name, content) VALUES (:name, :content)";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam("name", $name);
    $statement->bindParam("content", $content);
    $statement->execute();
}
 

function dataValidation(): void
{
    $errorMessage = [];

    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $content = trim($_POST['content']);
    $allowedSymbols = "/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/";
    $nameLength = 30;
    $contentLength = 1000;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://localhost/comments/index.php")
    {
        if (mb_strlen($name) > $nameLength) {
            $errorMessage['name'] = "Name should have less than 30 symbols";
        }
        elseif (mb_strlen($content) > $contentLength) {
            $errorMessage['content'] = "Commentary should have less than 1000 symbols";
        }
        elseif (empty($name)) {
            $errorMessage['name'] = "Enter your name";
        }
        elseif (empty($content)) {
            $errorMessage['content'] = "Enter your commentary";
        }
        elseif (!preg_match($allowedSymbols, $name)) {
            $errorMessage['name'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
        elseif (!preg_match($allowedSymbols, $content)) {
            $errorMessage['content'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return ['error'=>true/false, 'content'=>'Сообщение об ошибке/иное сообщение'];` Затем проверить, false или true error и делать нужное действие. Как вариант. global из кода выкиньте вообще, а то в аду особый котел будет

Comment: а что с global не так?) я не в курсе

Comment: Больше минусов, чем плюсов. С ними вы столкнетесь, когда ваша небольшая программка будет расти до полноценного ресурса. Если нужно больше подробностей, то погуглите..тема распространенная и в большинстве случаев расписана по плюсам и минусам )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
function addComment($pdo, $params ): void
{
    $result = false;
    if ( is_array( $params ) && count($params) > 0 && is_array(array_keys($params)) && count(array_keys($params)) > 0 ) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (name, content) VALUES (:name, :content)";
        if ( $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql) ) {
            foreach( array_keys($params) as $key => $value ) {
                $sth->bindParam( $key, $value);
            }
            $result = $sth->execute();
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
 
function dataValidation()
{
    $errorMessage = [];

    if ( isset($_POST) && is_array($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0 && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://localhost/comments/index.php")
    {
        foreach(['name', 'content'] as $fieldName ) {
            if ( isset($_POST[ $fieldName ]) && trim($_POST[ $fieldName ]) != '' ) {
                $maxLength = ( $fieldName != 'name' ? 1000 : 30 );
                if ( mb_strlen(trim($_POST[ $fieldName ])) > $maxLength ) {
                    if (!preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/", $_POST[ $fieldName ])) {
                        $errorMessage[ $fieldName ] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
                    }
                } else { $errorMessage[ $fieldName ] = ucfirst( $fieldName )." should have less than ".$maxLength." symbols"; }
            } else { $errorMessage[ $fieldName ] = "Enter your ".( $fieldName != 'name' ? 'commentary' : $fieldName ); }
        }
    }
    return $errorMessage;
}

if ( doValidation() && addComment( $pdo, $_POST ) ) {
  //Все отлично!
}
```